# How to implement Page-based pagination

Tags: javascript, api, rest, express, sequelize.js

Im trying to implement Page-based pagination on this particular endpoint but the problem Im faced is that the response body is not printing out the page, page_size and total results.

The URL is **http://localhost:3006/events/tickets?sort_by=name&page=1&page_size=2**

How do I get to return a Json body like this ?
Ideal Response Im trying to achieve

```
{
    content: [],               // respponse items
    page: 1,                   // current page
    results_per_page: 10,      // results per page
    total_pages: 10,           // total number of pages
    total_results: 100         // number of all results
}
```

```
const getTickets = (tickets) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {

      let query = `SELECT id, name, description, ticket_price, ticket_type
      FROM tickets`;

      let sort_by = tickets.sort_by;

      if(sort_by  ?? false) {
                
        query += ` ORDER BY ${sort_by}`;        
        if (sort_by) {
          query += (sort_by == 'desc' ? ` DESC` : ` ASC`);
        } 
      }

      let limit = tickets.page_size;

      let replacements = { limit: limit };

      if (limit) {
        query += ` LIMIT :limit`;
        
        replacements.limit = limit;
      }

      let offset = limit ? ((tickets.page - 1) * limit) : 0;
  
      if(offset) {
        query += ` OFFSET :offset `;
        
        replacements.offset = offset;
      };

      const ticket = await db.sequelize.query(
        query,
        {
          replacements: replacements,
          type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
        }
      );

      return resolve(ticket);
    } catch (err) {
      return reject(err)
    }
  })
}
```

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Tennis Finals",
        "description": "Finals: Tennis Team 1 vs Tennis Team 2",
        "ticket_price": 25,
        "ticket_type": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Testing Tickets",
        "description": "Description....",
        "ticket_price": 1000,
        "ticket_type": 30
    }
]
```

Comment: The code on the bottom is the response you are getting right?? And you want this response to be in 'content' field of the JSON above and the rest of the fields should be page and page size etc. right??
If that so, then when returning the response, you can make your custom object, and add the fields you required above. So like you can make an object with page and page_size key and assign them values that you got from endpoint request URL and also in 'content' field you can assign the response from database.

Comment: Why didn't you try to define a Sequelize model for `tickets` table and use `findAndCountAll` method of the model?

Comment: @ZaeemKhaliq Ive just created the custom object and assigned all the values including the response from the db in it. But the custom object is only showing on the debugger terminal on my IDE and not on the postman when I test the endpoint. Is there a way I can get it to display on postman so that its easy to integrate on the FE?

Comment: @Nifty Are you returning the object in response??? Also make sure the object is stringified by using `JSON.stringify(yourCustomObject)` on the custom object before returning the response.

Comment: const response = [ticket];
const page_object = { page: tickets.page };                
const results_per_page_object = { page_size: tickets.results_per_page };     

 const results = Object.assign(
        response,
        page_object,
        results_per_page_object,
);
JSON.stringify(results);
console.log(results);

return resolve(results)

Comment: @ZaeemKhaliq yes, I stringified the response but its still showing the normal json body response with the data and not the page and page_size ?

Comment: @Nifty This is the backend code right? So please show how are you returning the response to a request at particular endpoint. Show the full code, where you are calling the function (getTicket) and awaiting the response. Also show screenshot of what you are getting in console.log() and the postman result.

Comment: @Nifty The problem may also be occurring because in `Object.assign()` you've set the target object i.e., `response` as an array and not an object. Try to define object like: - `let results = {content:[...ticket],page:tickets.page, page_size:tickets.results_per_page} and then JSON.stringify(results)`